# Find "StringBetween" whole directory linux cli

Tags: regex, linux, find, command-line-interface

I have a mailserver with iredmail running.

We're sending out several newsletters per day, and the "bounced" ones are in the vmail folder.

I want to extract the "id" from these files without smtp usage, since i already have the whole mail content local.

```
"http://www.myserver.com/index.php?m=xxxxxxxxxx"
```

I want now to go through all files in a directory and find the first occurance of "xxxxxxxxx" in each file and save it to a text file, so that i can remove these id's from the mailling list database.

If possible via CLI.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command to find the first occurrence of id's in each file ,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=index\.php\?m\=)[^"]*' {} \; | sort -u
```

**Explanation:**

```
find         # command to find files are directories

.            # current directory(path on which the operation of find command is going to takes place)

-maxdepth 1  # don't search inside subdirectories.(ie; search only in the current directory)

-type f      # Only files

-exec grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=index\.php\?m\=)[^"]*' {} \;  # execute the grep command on only the founded files.

            -oP                          # (-o)print only the match,(-P) Perl-regex.
            -m 1                         # Grep to stop after first match occurs on each file.
            (?<=index\.php\?m\=)[^"]*    # A lookbehind is used here. It matches the text after `index.php?m=` upto the first occurrence of `"`. It helps to match the id's.
             {}                          # Founded files.
             \;                          # stops the find command.

sort -u      #  print only the unique id's.
```

Comment: Thanks again.. i'm such a da** noob in regex :( Answer acecpted :D